# Make an html links href property equal Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, href

If I have an html link, how can I make its href property equal an Ajax.ActionLink?
So that it would look something like this:

```
<a href="@Ajax.ActionLink(...)"></a>
```

The actionlink will return a partialview that I want to load into a div, so I need to use the ajax.actionlinks ajaxoptions property to do this.

**EDIT:**

I want my tag to look this:

```
<a href="@Ajax.ActionLink(...)">
    <span class="badge pull-right">@Convert.ToString(GPTooLowNew.Count())</span>
    Gross Profit Too Low on Product Sale
</a>
```

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with it. But I'm open to any sort of solution.

Comment: If you want an Ajax.ActionLink then you create it as `@Ajax.ActionLink(...)` which creates the `<a>` tag (not the other way around). I suggest you start with [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/)

Comment: But how do I get the <a> tag that this generates to include other html elements such as a <span> tag? Please see edit...

Comment: You cant (unless you want to create your own html helper). You can create you own html elements then use javascript/jquery to handle the `<a>` tags click event to provide the same functionally as `@Ajax.ActionLink()` or you can use javascript/[jquery to append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) new elements to the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

as you're using `ajax`

Here is way to do it in `javascript`:

```
window.onload=function(){
var links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
var link=links[i];
var href=link.getAttribute("href").toString();
link.setAttribute("href","@Ajax.ActionLink('"+href+"')"); // Assuming Ellipses are the href parameter passed to Ajax.ActionLink(...) function.
}
};
```

wrap this inside `</head> ... <script type='text/javascript'> Code Here </script>...</head>`
Hope it helps. Cheers :).

If you use Jquery, it'll be even simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Didn't work though. Getting a System.ArgumentException. No overload for method 'ActionLink' takes 1 argument(s).

Comment: Just try changing: `link.setAttribute("href","@Ajax.ActionLink('"+href+"')");` to `link.setAttribute("href","@Ajax.ActionLink()");` hope it helps

Comment: Which will create something like (depending on the options) `<a href="<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#CustomerList" href="/Home/Germany">Customer from Germany</a>"></a>`. Makes no sense to me and certainly not to a browser!